# Performance Visibility for Z3

Tags: z3

Is there a way to see what Z3 is doing under the hood? I would like to be able to see the steps it is taking, how long they take, how many steps, etc. I'm checking the equality of floating point addition/multiplication hardware designs with Z3's builtin floating point addition/multiplication. It is taking quite longer than expected, and it would be helpful to see what exactly it's doing in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with higher verbosity:

```
z3 -v:10
```

This will print a lot of diagnostic info. But the output is unlikely to be readable/understandable unless you're really familiar with the source code. Of course, being an open source project, you can always study the code itself: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

Answer (score 0):

If you're especially interested in e-matching and quantifiers, you can use the Axiom Profiler ([GitHub source](https://github.com/viperproject/axiom-profiler), [research paper](http://pm.inf.ethz.ch/publications/getpdf.php?bibname=Own&id=BeckerMuellerSummers19.pdf)) to analyse a Z3 trace. The profiler shows instantiation graphs, tries to explain instantiations (which term triggered, which equalities were involved), and can even detect and explain matching loops.

For this, run `z3 trace=true`, and open the generated trace file in the profiler. Note that the tool is a research prototype: I've noticed some bugs, it seems to work more reliable on Windows than on *nix, and it might not always support the latest Z3 versions.